# How to show Django timestamp in backend

Tags: django, django-models, timestamp

I'm using Django 1.6 as backend, what I want to do is to let users write their comments while watching the video. I wrote the field

```
datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

in the model.py, but in the Django back-end, I didn't see this column, how can I let it show in my admin? Thanks!

Comment: You mean it is not visible in Django admin?

Comment: yes, and I forget how we can modifier the name of field when showing in the backend, for example, I defined "datetime" in the model.py, but in the back-end we can see it as "Date"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `readonly_fields` option to you admin.py:

```
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('datetime',)
```

If you have `fields` option defined in you admin class, you'll also have to add `datetime` to the `fields` option:

```
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # display datetime in the changelist
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'datetime')
    # display datetime when you edit comments
    readonly_fields = ('datetime',)
    # optional, use only if you need custom ordering of the fields
    fields = ('title', 'body', 'datetime')

admin.site.register(Comment, CommentAdmin)
```

For more info, please see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: I still don't understand why I can not see this column, where can we modifer the display of site admin?

Comment: How does your current admin class for Comments look like?

Comment: Something like `from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import *

admin.site.register(Comment)`

Comment: I got an error: "Unknown field(s) (datetime) specified for Comment. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class CommentAdmin.", but when I added ` readonly_fields = ('datetime',)` it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a field of a model to be shown in admin by adding it to the ModelAdmin (in admin.py of the model's app):

```
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('datetime',)

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

And to set the short description that is displayed next to the field, you need to set `verbose_name` of the field, like the following (in models.py):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Uploaded at")
```

**Note:** You don't need to set `readonly_fields` since `DateTimeField` with `auto_now_add=True` arg will be read-only by default.